# Target `source` elements with jQuery in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer-9

I have the following JavaScript (jQuery) and HTML structure:

```js
$(function(){
  
  $('source').each(function(){
    console.log('a source element');
  });
  
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1200px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/300">
    <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
    <img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==">
  </picture>
</div>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I realise `picture` is not supported in IE9 so I'm working on some custom fallback logic.  Part of this fallback involves grabbing the `srcset` attribute from the `source` tags. However, it doesn't appear that jQuery can select the source elements in IE9 as, when running the example code above, nothing is logged to the console in that browser. Is anyone able to advise how to get jQuery to recognise source elements in IE9 (or whether it's even possible)?

Thanks

--
EDIT

Selecting the `picture` element is possible, but then selecting `$('picture').children()` again doesn't work. The `source` elements are completely ignored. Also tried adding classes to the `source` elements but again nothing is returned when using those as a selector.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to produce the issue on my side. After using the F12 developer tools to debug the JavaScript code, it seems that in IE9 mode, we could find the picture elements, but if we check its innerHTML property, we can see it only contains the img tag, not contains the source element, so we can not find it. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue.

As we all known, The [HTML  element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/source) specifies multiple media resources for the <**picture**>, the <**audio**> element, or the <**video**> element. I have test that if we change the picture to audio or video elements, then, we could find the source element. So, you could try to use them, instead of using the picture element.